# how to give name to sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint

I have created the sharepoint site . I want to assign the name as per www.something.com what settings I have to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming internal access

1) Setup a DNS entry on your internal DNS server so that www.something.com resolves to the IP address of your server.

2) SharePoint Central Administration > Operations > Alternate Access Mappings and change the server name in default to www.something.com

Comment: "Not running" gives me nothing to go on, you have to give details. Start with a ping www.something.com - does it return the correct IP address?

Answer (score -1):

You should extend your web application to a different zone (for example the internet zone) in central admin. Then you can specify the host header and port number.

Central admin -> application management -> create or extend web application -> extend an existing web application (for SharePoint 2007)

If your site needs to be available over the internet, be sure to setup your firewall and dns records correctly as well.

Comment: You don't need to extend - you can set the AAM on the existing site.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288609(office.12).aspx 

Read mistake 3, including the note.